# Concatenating data descriptions and aligning to data range

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have been trying to learn visual basic to write code to perform tasks when working with data in excel. I have been mostly copying snippets of code I find online and piecing them together. Currently, I have folders containing 10's of thousands of .csv files (data output from a CMM).

In each of these files column A consistently contains labels for the data and column B consistently contains the CMM data.

Currently, my program allows a user to select multiple .csv files and in a long roundabout way they all end up on one worksheet in excel with the data labels in the first column and the data in the next columns.

For example, if 10 CSV files are opened the data labels would be in the first column and the data would be in the next 10 columns.

The problem is that that the data labels are not aligned with the data and often each row of data has multiple labels.

I have been able to concatenate the data labels into one label for each row of data but cannot figure out how to align this label with the row of data.

At this point, I would be happy with a separate block of code that accomplishes this but... I suspect that my block of code that concatenates the labels could be easily modified to accomplish the task, I just haven't been able to figure it out.

So my code spits this out:

```
(Flatness) : Item (113)

Plane:RH_5_Mating_Surface

                                                             5.012  4.014  6.313  etc...

(Z) : Item (128) / (X) : Item (135)

Circle:Offset_Dowel_Hole

                                                             1.012  2.987  5.478  etc...

Circle:Cast_Hole_From_Offset_Dowel_Hole

                                                             2.147  7.895  4.258  etc...
```

Then this code concatenates the labels and spits them out in column B:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim concat As String

Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

Set rng1 = Range("A9:A" & Lastrow)   
concat = ""
For Each c In rng1
If c > 0 Then
    concat = concat & " " & c.Value
    concat = Trim(concat)
Else
    c.Offset(-1, 1).Value = concat
    concat = ""
End If
Next c
```

The result is:

```
(Flatness) : Item (113) Plane:RH_5_Mating_Surface

                                                             5.012  4.014  6.313  etc...


(Z) : Item (128) / (X) : Item (135) Circle:Offset_Dowel_Hole

                                                             1.012  2.987  5.478  etc...

Circle:Cast_Hole_From_Offset_Dowel_Hole

                                                             2.147  7.895  4.258  etc...
```

What I need is:

I cant figure out how to show it here but...

I need the rows to match up, also note, here it shows that the data and labels are offset by the same amount but in reality they are not. So my thinking is that I need it to search for the next row containing data and put the label next to it.

I feel like I can just change this part...

```
Else
    c.Offset(-1, 1).Value = concat
```

but I don't know how to do...

I tried nesting another "For Each" here instead similar to what its already doing but with a "For Each d In rng2" where "rng2" was the data column and it would look for the next row with data and place "concat" next to the data using "d.offset(-1, -1).Value = concat"

I couldn't figure out how to get it to work...

Comment: I suggest you mock up an example of how you want it and post a screenshot.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to post a picture...

Comment: Basically, each label on the left needs to be on the same row as the data on the right so that it looks like: label  data  data  data  etc...

Comment: Why are you using this offset `c.Offset(-1, 1)`? What if you do `c.Offset(, 1)`?

Comment: Go back to the data gathering step. I would use a `Dictionary` object to collect the data.  You could use the label as the key.  The properties would include a dictionary of the concatenated labels, where each item (concatenation) comes from a particular CSV file.  Then, for output, you merely iterate through the dictionary and it should be trivial to ensure the labels and data are on the same rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way of doing it.
Delete the empty cells and shift up in the columns. If the data order is consistent, they should line up correctly.

```
For i=1 to Lastrow
    If Range("A" & i).Value=""
        Range("A" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
    If Range("B" & i).Value=""
        Range("B" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next
```

You can change the range according to your sheet. Also, modify the code to use another 'IF' condition to check blanks, if that works better for your case.

Comment: Hmmm... that will not quite work here because there are more rows of data than there are rows of labels because sometimes there will be a label like "location of hole # 17" and the data will be an (x,y) location so there will be 2 rows of data... one row for x and another row for y... right now if I can just get the label to line up with the next row of data... in this case that would be the row with the "x" data...

Comment: So what if you just delete the top blank cells in the Data column. Then your top row lines up.

And then change the if condition to check if both the columns are empty and then delete those rows. Something like

If Range("A" & i).Value="" And Range("B" & i).Value=""
    'Delete the row
End If